# How to specify virtual machine name while vm deploy using ovf template in pyvmomi

Tags: python, pyvmomi

I am using pyvmomi to to deploy virtual machine to vCenter using ovf template. By default it takes virtual machine name as specified in .ovf file.
I am not able to figure out where in my code (i.e while creating import specifications or in ImportVapp) i can specify the new virtual machine name to override that in .ovf file.

Here is code snippet:

```
 # Create import specifications
ovfManager = self.session.content.ovfManager
specParams = vim.OvfManager.CreateImportSpecParams()
importSpec = ovfManager.CreateImportSpec(
            ovfDescriptor, resourcePool, datastore, specParams)

# Create virtual machine 
lease = resourcePool.ImportVApp(importSpec.importSpec,
                                        datacenter.vmFolder, host)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching in pyvmomi api documentation i found the solution to this:
While creating import specification parameters, we need to set 'entityName' attribute.

```
specParams = vim.OvfManager.CreateImportSpecParams(entityName='new_linux_vm')
```